# ssh input from text file

Tags: bash, ssh, shell-script, io-redirection

These two question is driving me crazy and I don't have good expertise of ssh. (but I suspect it is to do with redirection only)

The questions are,

> You want to pass multiple lines of input from a file called `abc.txt` to the `ssh` command.
>   Complete the command required to do this

`$ssh _ _ abc.txt`  (that is only two characters) (a details explanation would be helpful)

AND

> You want to pass multiple lines of input from a file called Remote.txt to `ssh` but all leading tabs in the subsequent input should be stripped. Complete the command to do this

`$ssh _ _ _ Remote.txt`

Comment: it seems to be some homework task... Can you explain why u require it exactly..

Comment: not exactly home work.. but kind of. it was asked in some interview questions. I know how to it in other way

Comment: what that file is containing ...whether its containing something like `user@sshserverip` ?

Comment: not specified in the question.. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass input from a *local* file to `ssh`, you should use input redirection like this:

```
ssh user@server < abc.txt
```

Are you sure the `_` must be really a single character? In that case this is possible if `x` is configured in `~/.ssh/config` as an alias to some user@host:

```
ssh x < abc.txt
```

I cannot answer Q2 because I don't really understand it. I suppose Remote.txt is on the remote.

As per the second question, I suppose Remote.txt is a file on the remote side, in which case the command should be of the form:

```
ssh user@server "bash < Remote.txt"
```

...but this does not fit the problem description with `_ _ _` and of course to remove the trailing tabs some more would be necessary like:

```
ssh user@server "bash < <(sed -e 's/^[    ]*//' Remote.txt)"
```

In other words this *does NOT* answer the second question. I hope this helps you  anyway understanding redirection when used with `ssh`.

**EDIT**

After reading the Q another time, since it says "passing multiple lines of input to ssh" suggests that we have to use redirection to ssh again, in which case the file must be local.

```
ssh user@server < <(sed 's/^[    ]*//' Remote.txt)
```

But again, I don't think this qualifies as an answer in the form `ssh _ _ _ Remote.txt`

Comment: you could run:
     `ssh user@server "sed ..." < Remote.txt`
if the file "Remote.txt" is a local file, although I agree the question is phrased in a way that it's not clear.

Comment: `ssh user@server "bash < Remote.txt"` is `ssh _ _ _ Remote.txt` and `ssh user@server "bash < <(sed -e 's/^[    ]*//' Remote.txt)"` is `ssh _ _ _ _ _ Remote.txt` . These command may work but the "question" is still unanswered.

Comment: I had the feeling too.. the question might got altered while flowing down to me. :)

Answer (score -3):

Ans 1.

```
$ssh user@server cat abc.txt
```

Ans 2.

```
$ssh user@server "sed 's/^[    ]//g' Remote.txt"
```

Comment: Neither of these suggestions do what the OP is asking.

Comment: Well the question was to fill in the blanks _ and these two command above work perfectly if you ask me. The first blank _ is always `user@server`, the second _ in the first command has to be exactly one word (or command) which in this case is `cat`. In the second command the second _ is for `sed` and third _ is for `'s/^[    ]//g'`. This sounds more like it unless you can change the question when you sitting in an interview.

Comment: Your first answer is incorrect. The question was to pass input from `abc.txt` to ssh, and your answer is not doing that.

Answer (score -3):

For the first part:

```
$ssh << abc.txt
```

For the second part:

```
$ssh <<- remote.txt
```